# Textexpander 5 optional section keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textexpander

I'm using TextExpander 5. Is it possible to use a keyboard instead of a mouse then working with a popup window with importing choices? Like, if I don't want to include a section I'd rather use my keyboard to uncheck a checkbox then reaching out for a mouse.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually completed such task by using Mac OS X built-in ability to TAB focusing on non-inputable UI elements.

You can change it at System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

At a bottom of a window you will found «Full Keyboard Access». This guy will help you to do that I was hoping to get (and finally got).

If you are interested in following my adventures on this, go here https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-count-how-many-times-a-key-was-pressed-since-boot/6618/15

tldr version of the link above;

> Found somewhat "almost-there" solution. I can check current status of this option by typing in terminal:
>
> defaults read -g AppleKeyboardUIMode
>
> It will return 0 (off) or 2 (on) dependent of current setting.

Right now, I'm using Keyboard Maestro Macro for doing this.